# Convert super() from Java into Swift

Tags: java, swift

I am trying to convert Java code into Swift, and I converted as follows, but wondering how to convert `super()` from Java into Swift.

**Java**

```
public class BFactory extends CompositeFactory {
     public BFactory(byte[] input) {
        super(input, CompositeFactory.MAX_SIZE);
     }
}
```

**Swift**

```
public class BFactory : CompositeFactory {
     init(input: UInt8) {
        // do not know what to put here
        //super(input, CompositeFactory.MAX_SIZE);
     }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call parent constructor when init a subclass in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438751/call-parent-constructor-when-init-a-subclass-in-swift)

Comment: Not really, I need some justification and explanation.

Comment: `super.init(...)` - Swift doesn't use "empty" constructors like Java, it uses `init` (although the compiler knows to convert `BFactory(...)` to `BFactory.init(...)`)

Comment: It sounds like what you probably want is to read some intros to swift, to understand how _it_ implements the core ideas of OO, so you know what to map Java constructs to.

Comment: @MadProgrammer `super.init(input, CompositeFactory.MAX_SIZE)`, right?

Comment: For justification / explanation, try reading this: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html