# C# to Swift Conversion: Constructors with inheritance

Tags: c#, swift, inheritance, constructor

I did a project in C# for a class that would use a tree to solve mathematical expressions. I had two classes : `ExpressionTree` and `ExpressionTreeLeaf`

I had two constructors for the `ExpressionTree`

```
 public ExpressionTree(string d)
    {
        Data = d;
        Left = null;
        Right = null;
    }
public ExpressionTree(string d, ExpressionTree left, ExpressionTree right)
    {
        Data = d;
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
    }
```

I also had an `ExpressionTreeLeaf` constructor

```
 public ExpressionTreeLeaf(int n) : base(n.ToString())
    {
        _num = n;
    }
```

I understand that the `:base(n.ToString())` is used to call the parent constructor. How do I do this in Swift?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438751/call-parent-constructor-when-init-a-subclass-in-swift

Comment: Do you want to still be able to create `ExpressionTreeLeaf`s using the first constructor? e.g. `new ExpressionTreeLeaf("foo")`. I guess not, right?

Comment: @Sweeper the idea with the ExpressionTreeLeaf is that the data contained is always a number, not an operator. So I want to be able to use it in that sense. I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by simply calling `super.init`:

```
class ExpressionTree {
    let data: String
    let left: ExpressionTree?
    let right: ExpressionTree?
    
    init(data: String, left: ExpressionTree? = nil, right: ExpressionTree? = nil) {
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    }
}

class ExpressionTreeLeaf: ExpressionTree {
    init(_ n: Int) {
        super.init(data: "\(n)") // <----- here!
    }
}
```

The constructors of `ExpressionTree` won't be inherited by `ExpressionTreeLeaf` in this case, just like in your C# code. Though do note that there are [conditions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222) under which they *are* inherited - they are just not satisfied in this case.

---

This is just my opinion, but I think expression trees are much easier to build (much less code) if you use recursive enums with associated values, rather than inheritance. There is an [example](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID536) right in the Swift Guide. Here's another example that I just came up with:

```
enum BinaryOperator {
    case plus, minus, times, divide // and more...
}

enum UnaryOperator {
    case plus, minus // and more...
}

indirect enum Expression {
    case number(Int)
    case binaryOp(Expression, BinaryOperator, Expression)
    case unaryOp(UnaryOperator, Expression)
}
```